# C# Change straight quotes to curly quotes on the fly in winforms RichTextBox instance

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

VS 2019, C# WinForms application, .Net Framework 4.8, RichTextBox

I'd like to change a straight quote (") to an appropriate curly quote (“ or ”) on the fly as the user types into a rich text box.

The idea would be to look one character ahead in the doc, and if it's white space (or the char is the first char in the doc), then use “, otherwise use ”.

Is that possible with this control?

**[Edit]**

Well, I found the answer and it was dead simple if anyone wants to use it:

Use the Shortcut CTRL + ' (apostrophe) to toggle "Smart Quotes" on and off which, in the end, is what I was looking to do. I'm not sure which versions of the RichTextBox support this feature, but the latest one does.

Comment: what effort have you made to solving the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The term for this feature is known as "Smart Quotes" and is supported by the underlying Rich Edit control.

The feature is activated/deactivated while typing in the control using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Single Quote (')</kbd>.

The feature requires the [Rich Edit Version 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/about-rich-edit-controls#rich-edit-version-30) or greater.  For .Net Versions 4.7 and higher this is not a problem as the Rich Edit version 5 is the default underlying control.  For .Net versions lower the 4.7, the Rich Edit version 2 is the default; as such a custom RichEdit control would be need to enable this feature.

Do note that font used will greatly impact the appearance of the *curly* quotation marks.

[image]

Also note the other [Rich Edit Shortcut Keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/about-rich-edit-controls#rich-edit-shortcut-keys).

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. I understand about the different font representations of the curlies which is fine. Is there any way to detect if that feature is active on a given form and/or handle the associated event?

Comment: @user1325543, as far as I know, there is no way to query the rich edit control for this state.  As it is initially off, you could monitor the keys sent to the control to track the smart quote state.